# Using HTML5 canvas with SVG

Tags: html, canvas, svg, data-uri

I"m developing a diagramming application in HTML5/JavaScript. All drawing is done with [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG), using Raphael or qooxdoo SVG (not settled yet). The drawing area should use custom background image. The image is too big to be downloaded (several megabytes for 2560x1600 Retina resolution), that's why I construct it on the fly, composing it from tiles and applying bitmap effects. For that, I use [HTML5 canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas). After that, the resulting background image has to be made accessible from SVG. To achieve that, I export a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) from the canvas, and use `<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."/>` inside SVG.

This works for simple examples, but I'm a bit concerned about memory usage in production. Given that the image takes 12MB in memory (2560 * 1600 *3 bytes ber pixel), how much additional memory will be used? I suppose that at least some megabytes will be allocated to store base64-encoded PNG-compressed representation as data URI, and another 12 megabytes will go to the buffer for the SVG `<image>` element.

I wonder if there is a method to short-circuit this and to avoid redundant image encoding-decoding?

Comment: The need for the image to be an actual SVG element is stipulated by the requirement to implement panning/zooming/rotation of the whole drawing area, which is much easier to do when the background is a part of the SVG tree.
Additionally, SVG has to be exported to PNG on the client side (I use [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) for that).

Comment: On Firefox you could check the memory used via about:memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go around the base64 part with `canvas.toBlob(callback)` and `window.URL.createObjectURL()`. Other than that I don't think there is a place for you to further limit memory usage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.URL.createObjectURL

The `toBlob()` method can be shimmed on some browsers: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob